# How to transfer RabbitMQ message into Amazon S3 bucket in csv file format and query the bucket using Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, rabbitmq, amazon-athena

I'm working on a hard app that read a RabbitMQ message and transfer it into an Amazon S3 bucket.

The RabbitMQ message should be stored as a .csv file format in the S3 bucket.

The Amazon S3 bucket should be connected to AWS Athena to query on it.

Can anyone who has a clarification help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query csv tables stored s3 through athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52041500/query-csv-tables-stored-s3-through-athena)

Comment: are you looking for a tutorial/ guidance or do you have a specific problem?

Comment: @Aarif I would love to have a guidance about that, of course if it's not disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for how to create an Athena table that reads CSV data: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/lazy-simple-serde.html

There are also many questions here on StackOverflow that ask the same thing, see for example [Query csv tables stored s3 through athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52041500/query-csv-tables-stored-s3-through-athena?noredirect=1&lq=1)